# POSIX Message Queue Receive Timeout

Tags: c, queue, posix

```
if((nbytes=mq_receive (qid_recv, (pchar_t)in_buffer, msg_buffer_size, NULL)) != -1) {
            printf("nbytes is %ld\n", nbytes);
}else{
     perror("recv_data");
     printf("nbytes is %ld\n", nbytes);
```

How to exit from the mq_receive if there is no message is received.Is there any possiblity for give a timeout.Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to `mq_timedreceive()`, you can also set the `O_NONBLOCK` when you open the queue with `mq_open()`.  Per [the `mq_open()` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mq_open.html):

> `O_NONBLOCK`
>       Determines whether an `mq_send()` or `mq_receive()` waits for resources or messages that are not currently available, or fails with errno set to `EAGAIN`; see `mq_send` and `mq_receive` for details.

Per [the `mq_receive()` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mq_receive.html):

> If the specified message queue is empty and `O_NONBLOCK` is set in the message queue description associated with `mqdes`, no message shall be removed from the queue, and `mq_receive()` shall return an error.

Comment: When i use mq_timedreceive and set the O_NONBLOCK in mq_open,it returns error when no message is received.

Comment: @Einsenheim Yes, and `errno` should be set to `EAGAIN`.  That's how you know there was no message.

Comment: Thanks Andrew Henle.

Comment: These timeouts are non-monotonic though... so in something like an embedded system connected to GPS... this could cause funny behavior

Answer (score 2):

You can use mq_timedreceive function.